# Decoding and getting the filename* from ContentDisposition with Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, http-headers

this is a snippet  from my code:

```
    for (Header header : headers) {
        if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(header.getName(), "Content-Disposition")) {
            String headerValue = header.getValue();
            ContentDisposition cd = getContentDisposition(headerValue);
            String filename = cd.getParameter("filename*");
}
}
```

now what i have under filename  is   myFileName%EB%38%AA.txt

i am able to get full name with

```
 filename=    java.net.URLDecoder.decode(cd.getParameter("filename*"), "UTF-8")
```

And the acctual result is

```
filename = UTF-8''myFileNameイイケ.txt
```

the name is good, but the initial of `UTF-8''` is bad for me .

is there a way to get the encoding from the ContentDisposition ? or from the header ?

or a better way to remove the encoding from the file name during creating ?
i would like to support all encoding and not explicitly mention it.